# using arraylist to set , get data during xml parsing in android

Tags: android, arraylist, store, local-storage, xml-parsing

I am doing xml parsing and it is working fine as i have printed the content in log cat in my
parser class where it checks for attribute value.

I have no problem with parsing
I have problem with saving the content so that i can see the content on my activity.
Since the content in xml will be having repetitve tasks i think simple set / get methods wont do it.

I am looking for some guidance or tutorial link which will let me use array list in most flexible way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Use Enhanced For Loop Syntax](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/design/performance.html#foreach)